# iphone-How to get randomly created UIImageViews to move down the screen at a constant rate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, random, uiimageview

Background:

I am using x-code version 3.1.4 and an iphone simulator version 3.1.

Right now I am building a game where a car (portrayed by a UIImageView) moves left and right using two buttons (left and right). That part works fine. However, I am trying to randomly spawn UIImageViews at the top that will go down at a constant rate. I am able to get one UIImageView to move using this:

```
-(void)moveMeteor{

    iv.center=CGPointMake(iv.center.x, iv.center.y + 1); 
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveMeteor) withObject:iv afterDelay:0.01];
```

}

where iv is a UIImageView and I call this function when I click a button. However, I want to create randomly spawning UIImageViews. So, I did this using this code:

```
-(void)addViews: (NSTimer *) aTimer {
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Meteor.png"]];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (350), arc4random() % (5), 35, 35);
    [iv setFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
```

}

I call this function by clicking a start button which does this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(addViews:)    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I thought about using tags by changing the addViews function to :

```
-(void)addViews: (NSTimer *) aTimer {
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Meteor.png"]];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (350), arc4random() % (5), 35, 35);
    [iv setFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
    iv.tag=tagStart;  
    [self moveMeteor:tagStart]; 
    tagStart = tagStart+1;
```

}
(the initial value of tagStart is 1);

and changing the move function to:

```
-(void)moveMeteor:(int)tag{
    UIImageView *test= (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagStart];
    test.center=CGPointMake(test.center.x, test.center.y + 1); 
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveMeteor) withObject:tagStart afterDelay:0.01];
    [test release];
```

I am very confused on how to resolve this issue. The problem is either that my move function cannot handle so many moving things at a time, my tag system is faulty, my *test is faulty, or that I am calling to many functions at the same time, or something else. Please help and give me a solution to this annoying problem.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with your question, but... If possible, I highly recommend upgrading your version of Xcode!

Comment: Anything wrong with animating the frame to the end position with a set duration rather than trying to manage all of the frames yourself?

Comment: @Wain how would I be able to do that animation? Also, wouldn't I need to manage the frames myself because I am going to add collision detectors to the UIImageViews later

Answer (score 0):

A better option than `performSelector` is `NSTimer`, and a better option again is `CADisplayLink`. You limit of performance will probably be using `UIImageView` and the associated overhead with moving and redrawing them all, so you may want to change to use `CALayer`s instead. But, change one thing at a time.

For the meteors, I'd hold them all in an array and then each time your `moveMeteor` method is called, iterate through the array and move each one. Your tag method could work but will be less efficient (you're missing a loop to iterate through the tags basically).

---

```
-(void)moveMeteors {
    for (UIImageView *test in self.meteors) {
        test.center = CGPointMake(test.center.x, test.center.y + 1); 
     }
}
```

If you have an array called `meteors` that you add your new meteors to, and a timer calls `moveMeteors` periodically.

Comment: The problem with the array method is that I am making a bunch of UIImageViews, hypothetically, an infinite amount. The meteors will never stop coming. If I have an array, only a finite amount of meteors will spawn. In addition, how would I implement NSTimer or CADisplayLink?

Comment: The array is just a record of the *current* meteors, when they go off screen they are removed. It's just an easy way of storing them so you can move them all. The timer / display link is just a trigger to call your method to move all the meteors (currently your method just moves one).

Comment: And I should use a for loop to move each indivisual meteor?

Comment: In addition, once I call an element of the array, how would I implement it into the move function. For example, if I were to get the first element of the array using a for loop, how would I let my moveMeteor method know what UIImageView I am reffering to?